# thread and exception safe way of using HDFStore files

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, pytables, hdfstore

The following code snippet:

```
    HDFStore = pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore
    lock = threading.RLock()
    with lock:
        store = HDFStore('my_datafile.hdf','r')
        data_frame = store['my_series']
        store.close()
    return data_frame['my_column']
```

is executed in response to web requests, so it is possibly executed on multiple threads at the same time. It is also possible that the execution is interrupted before the store.close is called.

I'm experiencing some troubles (exceptions in the HDFStore library, or empty data returned) in a non reproducible way.

What is the correct way to make this code thread-safe and to be sure that the file is correctly closed upon exceptions?

With some investigation I found that HDFStore has a caching mechanism for opened files... maybe this might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for reference, see pandas [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#notes-caveats)

and just release PyTables 3.1 [release notes](http://pytables.github.io/latest/release-notes/RELEASE_NOTES_v3.1.x.html)

This *should* work on PyTables 3.0.0. As long as you are **not writing the file anywhere else** (iow it already exists).

You can try doing this as well:

```
with get_store('my_datafile.hdf',mode='r') as store:
    return store['my_series']
```

which will automatically close it for you (I dont think this is thread-safe per say, but maybe if you put it within your `with lock:` it will be thread-safe.

If you are **only** reading, then you don't care about being threadsafe at all. **DO NOT UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES** try to write in multiple threads (or even processes). This will blow your file up.

PyTables 3.1 was just released that changes the file caching mechanism at least on a lower HDF5 version, do to see your version:

```
import tables
tables.get_hdf_version()
```

I don't know the effect this will have on thread safe-ness.

Comment: I think I have pytables version 2.3.1 ('module' object has no attribute 'get_hdf_version'). In the 3.1 release notes it says: "PyTables no longer uses shared/cached file handlers. This change somewhat improves support for concurrent reading allowing the user to safely open the same file in different threads for reading" so, maybe, there was a serious problem also with concurrent reading.

Comment: Thank you so much also for pointing out the risks of concurrent writing (even if it is more unlikely in my case, it would be destructive!). Do you think it would be safe to write to a temporary file and then move (mv) the temporary to the target file? Or it would be better to use locks (threading and/or process)?

Comment: concurrent reading works just fine in multi-threading/processes. the change in 3.1 was more to align PyTables with how the underlying HDF5 protocol works. That said, it is possible it was buggy in < 3.0.0

Comment: You can write from a single process/thread to a single unique file, no problem. Just don't try to write to the **same** file, even different nodes with more than one process/thread.